Visual Studio Code performing syntax checking of python files in the current folder
Does anyone know if there is a way to tell Visual Studio Code to only perform the Python syntax checking for the CURRENT file being executed, instead of checking ALL Python files found in the current folder?
I have a bunch of .py files that are in progress and have syntax issues, but I want to ignore these while I work on one file at a time.
Any help would be great!
Eric
